# Prove that there exists only one prime number of the form $p^2−1$ where $p≥2$ is an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

By factoring  $p^2 − 1$, we have $(p + 1)(p - 1)$.

I know that $p = 2$ which gives $3$ is the only solution.

However, how do I prove that $p = 2$ is the only integer which gives a prime?

Comment: Because of the $p-1$ factor...

Comment: for any number>$2$, $p-1$ will give you a factor > $1$

Comment: any other solution can't be prime because it can be decomposed as a product of two numbers, neither of which equals 1 by the work you've already shown

Answer (score 8):

If $p>2$, both  $p+1$ and $p-1$ are $>1$, hence $p^2-1$ is composite.

Answer (score 0):

In $p^2-1=(p-1)(p+1)$ give a prime number only and only if p-1 is 1 so that p+1 will be the only prime factor. So n must be 2 and its the only one which can give us a prime(3).
I better suggest you to think about $$n^2-m=p$$ where 'n' is an natural number and m<$n^2$ such that 'p' will be a prime number.